# WPF C# Show Window on Keypress

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to show a Window only when I press a specific key combination.
At start the Window is not visible and has no focus. When I press for example three keys together the window shows up.

Is this even possible in WPF? And how?

Comment: Have you already tried something? Please show us your current progress and describe the *particular* problem you're encountering. Also, please read the [ask] topics to get informed how to ask a well-received question.

Comment: How is the solution to this different from any basic explanation of how to capture keypresses, combined with how to open a new window? Both of these are easily found online.

Comment: The Idea is that the Application is minimized to a tray icon and I've got a hardware device which is a simple button. I press the button and the Windows maximize. Everything I tried must have the focus on the Window. :(

Answer (score 2):

If your application is started, you must have the focus in some window.
In that window you can add a method that handle a `Keyup` or `KeyDown` event.
In that event you can control the keys pressed and open the new window. For example:

```
Private Sub dataGrid_PreviewKeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
    If e.Key = Key.Enter Then
        Dim newWindow As CustomWindow = New CustomWindow()
        newWindow.ShowDialog()
    End If
End Sub
```

Hope it help.